# Can I use Windows dialog boxes for moving / overwriting files?

Tags: windows

I'm making a program that will move around quite huge sets of files, sometimes they will overwrite other files and I'd like to use the "classic" XP style popup windows that lets the user choose if you want to replace files or not etc.

The program is written in Qt and will run exclusively on Windows XP, can I use say some kind of Win32 function to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Post that as an answer and I'll switch to that one

Comment: Feel free to edit your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Raymond Chen points out in a comment, SHFileOperation does the trick.